# Nav bar is covered by following text

Tags: html, css

I have a simple header with an img and a nav bar. I'd like to have the nav bar appear below the img (which is what happens) however the nav bar shows up behind the following text. I can't figure out how get the text below the nav bar and stop covering it (already tried a clear).

I'd like to mention I'm new at this so i could have over looked something very simple.

The wonderful jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/k2qQN/

Then here's my html:

```
<

header role="banner">
        <img src="../assets/images/autologo.png" alt="A and B automotive logo" />
        <nav role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about-us/about-us.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#getting-in-touch">Getting in Touch</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-the-shop/about-the-shop.html">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div role="main">
        <section id="services" title="Small overview of service">
            <h1>Title for content</h1>
            <p> At <a href="getting-in-touch">Some shop</a> Some random text following infoome random text following infoome random text following infoome random text following infoome random text following infoome random text following infoome random text following infoome random text following infoome random text following infoome random text following info</p>

        </section>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    }

header {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    }

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    }
```

Comment: which browser are you looking at ?

Comment: The fiddle looks good on firefox... it could be cause of the image height:100% maybe? As the image does not load ofcourse

Comment: Ah for the jsdiffle your right it shows up correctly because in firefox there is no empty box for the image. For chrome and IE9 you an see the problem im having.

Comment: I'm trying to do my first 'responsive web design' which is why im using percentages and not px's. When you resize the browser the image will be 100% in the 20% that the header container is in. In essence the image is always 20% of the top of the page.

Comment: but then you should either place the nav bar outside the header or do you want the nav bar to be overlayed on the image?

Answer (score 1):

Your image inside the header uses all the header's height. So either change the image's height by using this CSS:

```
header img {
    height:123px; /* or another value smaller than the header's height of 100% */
}
```

or don't set the header's height:

```
header {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the div with the `role="main"` a top margin. Give it an id or class first so you can refer to it more easily, then do this:

```
#main-div {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That would completely work but im trying to do my first 'responsive web design' site and stay with percentages so that the site scales to hd tv's and smartphones the same. I could do a percentage instead of 100px's maybe.

Comment: Yep a percentage margin might work, although it would probably be best to go with the solution given by @uruk, his is the best way, I was just giving a possible alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

header has `height:20%`, that is why it is overlapping the below div. Make `img` height as `max-height:100%` and header as `height:auto`

```
header {
    height:auto;
    width: 100%; 
    }

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k2qQN/1/)**

Comment: That would completely work but the image is a huge file so that it can scale up to an hd tv size. If I did 100% of that it would take up the whole screen. Thats why its in the 20% header so that the 100% img is always 20% of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your header has a fixed height. The navigation is overflowing but the content is not being pushed down. Either let the header take the height it needs or set `overflow: hidden;` on it to hide the overflowing content.